# ¿Cómo agregar un elemento a un arreglo en C?

Tags: c, array

Se debe agregar un elemento de una entrada que el usuario proporciona a un arreglo de 1000 elementos. El arreglo es de tipo `Receta` y se llama `recetas` pero no sé cómo se hace para agregar la entrada del usuario al array.

Adjunto código:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//Prototipo de estructuras

struct Receta;
struct BaseDatos;
struct Ingrediente;

struct Ingrediente
{
   string num;
   double cant;
   string unidadM;

};
struct Receta
{
   string nombre;
   int porciones;
   Ingrediente ingredientes[100];
   int cantidad;

  //Constructor
   Receta()
   {}

   void agregarReceta()
   {
   cout<<"Escriba el nombre de la receta: ";
   cin>>nombre;
   }       
};

struct BaseDatos
{
    Receta recetas[1000];
    int cantRecetas;
};
```

Comment: Hola Fabricio, deberías añadir algo más de información ¿has intentado algo hasta ahora? ¿con qué dificultades te estás encontrando? Esas partes son esenciales, especialmente porque como se indica en el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): las preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo.

Comment: Proporciona más información, si el elemento que vas a ingresar es en una posición exacta del arreglo o en un orden secuencial.

Comment: Saludos! Tengo una dificultad que es que el programa no me compila, porque tampoco sé cómo hacer el llamado de la funcion `agregarReceta()` la cual se encuentra dentro de la estructura `Receta`, desde el main, el cual se encuentra en otro archivo llamado main.cpp. Sin embargo me gustaría primero poder completar la función de `agregarReceta()`@AlvaroMontoro

Comment: @JohnVanegas No debe ser en una posición exacta, pues al ir agregando recetas éstas se van colocando en orden secuencial, entonces sería al final del arreglo

Comment: que error de compilación te sale?

Answer (score -1):

Recuerda que es C y no c++, las cosas varian, te recomiendo que leas un poco de captura de datos, son muy diferentes.
Sería algo:

```
char nombre[30]; 

  void agregarReceta()
   {

   printf ("Escriba el nombre de la receta:");
   fgets(nombre, 30, stdin);

   return;
   }
```

Nota: "stdin" limpia el buffer